# Error de dirección de carpeta con Jquery y Ajax

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo un código de **Jquery** para recargar una sesión de mi sitio web en tiempo real cada 1 segundo para lograr traer de la base de datos las publicaciones de los usuarios en tiempo real.

Pero resulta que cada vez que refresco la pagina me esta mostrando todo bien la publicación del usuario pero desde que pasa el segundo que refresca la sesión me esta lanzando un error con la dirección de la carpeta de **connection**. La dirección de la carpeta esta bien escrita porque funciona de maravilla antes de yo intentar refrescar en tiempo real la pagina ya la dirección a la **connection** funcionaba de maravilla. Ojo la dirección de la **connection** esta bien escrita.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código para recargar en tiempo real la pagina:**

```
function tiempoReal()
    {
        var tabla = $.ajax({
            url:'./publication/publication.php',
            dataType:'text',
            async:false
        }).responseText;

        document.getElementById("publication").innerHTML = tabla;
    }
    setInterval(tiempoReal, 1000);
```

Le explicaré un poco lo que hace este código. Lo que hice es que cree una función para recargar en tiempo real el archivo donde tengo la logica de PHP para sacar las publicaciones de los usuarios que es: `url:'./publication/publication.php',` OJO: la dirección esta escrita correctamente a pesar de que solo tiene un punto y una barra invertida para indicar que debe salir de la carpeta actual ya intente colocar los dos puntos y ahí si que no funciona para nada.

Este archivo *select-publication.js* que es donde esta el código que les acabo de colocar que es para refrescar la pagina en tiempo real, lo estoy mandando a llamar en la pagina `'./publication/publication.php'` que es donde esta el **HTML** que a su vez esta requerida por el archivo *home.php* que es donde esta requerida todas las publicaciones.

**Archivo publication/publication.php: que es el archivo donde esta todo el html de las publicaciones**

```
<?php require_once('./backend/select-publication.php') ?>
<?php foreach($result as $post) : ?>
<!-- Card de publicacion -->
<div id="publication" class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m7 xl6">
        <div class="card">

            <div>
                <br>
                <img src="images/yo.jpg" alt="carla" class="col s2 m2 xl2 img-adaptable circle">
                <span class="flow-text pink-text"><?php echo $post['name'].' '.$post['surname'] ?></span>
                <span class="right">
                    <i class="material-icons left">more_vert</i> 
                </span><br>
                <small class="grey-text">
                    Publicado el <?=form_fecha($post['create_at_pub'])?>
                </small><br><br>
            </div>

            <div class="card-image">
            <img src="./photo/<?php echo $post['photo_pub'] ?>" alt="Publicaci&oacute;n de <?php echo $post['name'].' '.$post['surname'] ?>" class="materialboxed">
            <span class="card-title"><?php echo $post['name'].' '.$post['surname'] ?></span>
            <!-- <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light white">
            
                Imagen del usuario que publico
                <img src="images/yo.jpg" alt="carla" height="60" class="img-adaptable">

            </a> -->
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
            <!-- <p class="grey-text">
                <i class="material-icons left">more_vert</i> 
                Publicado el 07 de Febrero de 2021
            </p><br> -->
            
            <p><?php echo $post['messeger_pub'] ?></p><br>

            <div class="divider"></div><br>

            <!-- Reacciones -->
            <div class="row">

                <!-- Like -->
                <div class="col s6">
                    <a href="" class="black-text">
                        <i class="material-icons left small">favorite_border</i>
                        <span class="flow-text black-text">10</span>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <!-- Comments -->
                <div class="col s6">
                    <span id="click-comment" class="black-text right">
                        <i class="material-icons left small">comment</i>
                        <span class="flow-text black-text">2</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- Area de texto para escribir un comentario -->
            <div id="view-comment" class="hide row">
            <div class="divider"></div>
                <form class="col s12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">comment</i>
                        <textarea id="comment" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                        <label for="comment">Escribe un comentario...</label>
                        </div>

                        <button class="btn waves-effect btn-color right" type="submit" name="action">Comentar
                            <i class="material-icons left">send</i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Como pueden ver estoy haciendo un **foreach** para recorrer todas las publicaciones. En la parte de arriba esta el require donde se encuentra la logica de PHP para sacar todas las publicaciones. OJO, todo el código funcionaba a la perfección antes de yo incluir el código de Jquery para refrescar la pagina en tiempo real. Por esa razón yo opino que el problema esta en el código de arriba donde esta el jquery.

Si necesitan mas información solo háganmelo saber.

Comment: Desde aquí vamos con un problema... Nunca utilices AJAX para hacer cambios en tiempo real.. tantas peticiones harán que el servidor se caiga... para cambios en tiempo real se usan Sockets

Comment: Además, no tendría mucho sentido usar jQuery solo para una petición AJAX (si ese es tu caso), puedes reemplazarlo con [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch) (Ya que aseguras que el problema se origina tras usar jQuery)

Comment: Sii, el problema se origino desde que comencé a utilizar Jquery

Comment: Parece que el problema es que la carpeta `backend` no está dentro de `publication`, supongo que están al mismo nivel, por lo que deberías incluir el archivo con `require_once '../backend/select-publication.php';`. El problema sería si usas el mismo script (`./publication/publication.php`) desde otros archivos, en otros niveles. Y no, el problema no es jQuery, es de rutas.

Comment: `backend` esta es una carpeta que esta en la raíz del proyecto al igual que la carpeta `publication`

Comment: Los mensajes muestran claramente que hay errores en las rutas de los archivos, no los está encontrando. Eso es lo primero que debes corregir si quieres que el código funcione. Luego, como bien dice @anythingg habrá quizá que pensar en algo más ligero para lanzar/buscar esas actualizaciones. Y, en caso de decidir hacerlo desde Javascript, lo lógico sería programar un temporizador que lance la petición. Pero en fin, si las rutas están mal, nada funcionará mientras eso no se corrija.

Comment: @A.Cedano Quiero corregir ese problema pero no encuentro la solución, por favor me puedes ayudar ?

Comment: Dinos en qué carpeta está el archivo que estás llamando en el parámetro `url`  de la petición Ajax y dinos en qué carpeta está el script actual (el que hace la petición Ajax). Pon un pequeño árbol de directorio o una captura de pantalla donde se vea cada archivo para uno poder ubicarse.

Comment: @A.Cedano En esta captura de pantalla logre abarcan todo el directorio donde tengo el problema, las capetas que están abierta y los archivos que están coloreados son los que utilizo y donde tengo el problema https://ibb.co/xmPtN6C

Comment: ¿En qué archivo exactamente tienes tu función `tiempoReal()`?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119510/discussion-between-braylin-ivan-payano-and-a-cedano).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre solucionar el problema después de estudiarlo por mucho tiempo. Resulta que el archivo que esta en carpeta "publication/publication.php" al hacer el refresh no entraba a los includes a leer los demás archivos que eran de suma importancia y por tal razón me lanzaba esos errores de redirección. Lo que hice para solucionar el problema fue colocar la conexión y la funciones necesarias dentro de ese archivo para que cuando ocurra el refresh lea todo sin tener que lanzar los errores por no lograr leer los demás archivos necesarios para funcionar.

**publication/publication.php:**

```
<?php
// Conexion a la base de datos
try{
  $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=geyland', 'root', '');
}catch(PDOExeption $e){
  echo "Lo sentimos, ha ocurrido un error nuestros ingenieros trabajan para solucionarlo: " . $e->getMessage();
  die();
} 

// Formatear fecha
function fecha($fecha){
    $times = strtotime($fecha);
    $meses = ['Enero','Febrero','Marzo',
            'Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto',
            'Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'];

    $dia = date('d', $times);
    $mes = date('m', $times) - 1;
    $anio = date('Y', $times);

    $fecha = "$dia de " . $meses[$mes] . " del $anio";
    return $fecha;

}

 // sacar todo lo que coicida con la busqueda
 $stetament = $conexion->prepare(
    "SELECT users.id_user, users.name, users.surname, users.photo_profile, publication.id_pub, publication.id_user_pub, publication.messeger_pub, publication.photo_pub, publication.create_at_pub FROM publication INNER JOIN users WHERE users.id_user = publication.id_user_pub ORDER BY publication.id_pub DESC"
);

$stetament->execute(array());
$result = $stetament->fetchAll();

?>
<?php foreach($result as $post) : ?>
<?php $fecha = $post['photo_pub'] ?>
<!-- Card de publicacion -->
<div id="publication" class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m7 xl6">
        <div class="card">

            <div>
                <br>
                <img src="images/yo.jpg" alt="carla" class="col s2 m2 xl2 img-adaptable circle">
                <span class="flow-text pink-text"><?php echo $post['name'].' '.$post['surname'] ?></span>
                <span class="right">
                    <i class="material-icons left">more_vert</i> 
                </span><br>
                <small class="grey-text">
                    Publicado el <?=fecha($post['create_at_pub'])?>
                </small><br><br>
            </div>

            <div class="card-image">
            <img src="./photo/<?php echo $post['photo_pub'] ?>" alt="Publicaci&oacute;n de <?php echo $post['name'].' '.$post['surname'] ?>" class="materialboxed">
            <span class="card-title"><?php echo $post['name'].' '.$post['surname'] ?></span>
            <!-- <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light white">
            
                Imagen del usuario que publico
                <img src="images/yo.jpg" alt="carla" height="60" class="img-adaptable">

            </a> -->
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
            <!-- <p class="grey-text">
                <i class="material-icons left">more_vert</i> 
                Publicado el 07 de Febrero de 2021
            </p><br> -->
            
            <p><?php echo $post['messeger_pub'] ?></p><br>

            <div class="divider"></div><br>

            <!-- Reacciones -->
            <div class="row">

                <!-- Like -->
                <div class="col s6">
                    <a href="" class="black-text">
                        <i class="material-icons left small">favorite_border</i>
                        <span class="flow-text black-text">10</span>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <!-- Comments -->
                <div class="col s6">
                    <span id="click-comment" class="black-text right">
                        <i class="material-icons left small">comment</i>
                        <span class="flow-text black-text">2</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- Area de texto para escribir un comentario -->
            <div id="view-comment" class="hide row">
            <div class="divider"></div>
                <form class="col s12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">comment</i>
                        <textarea id="comment" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                        <label for="comment">Escribe un comentario...</label>
                        </div>

                        <button class="btn waves-effect btn-color right" type="submit" name="action">Comentar
                            <i class="material-icons left">send</i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```